# c++ equivalent of this code below (sprintf)

Tags: c++, c, cout, printf

What is the C++ equivalent of the code below?

```
sprintf(name,"jari%d.jpg",rank+42+size);
```

help me how to change it to c++. can anyone help me?

Comment: `std::stringstream` is a rough equivalent, but not an exact one since it lacks the danger of buffer overflows. If you want to simulate that in C++, you can just do `std::string("")[100] = 'a';`.

Comment: For something like this with just one argument, `std::to_string` works well also.

Comment: @chris, `to_string` is a fine choice if you're working in C++11 or later (which I usually am), but it's not available in C++03.  Just a caveat.

Comment: this is my code char name[100];
   sprintf(name,"E:/tigaouts/Debug/jari2.jpg",rank+42+size); how to make it in c++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest an `ostringstream`:

```
string name;
{
    ostringstream oss;
    oss << "jari" << (rank+42+size) << ".jpg";
    name = oss.str();
}
```

Details:  To use this solution, you'll want `#include <sstream>` and pull `ostringstream` into scope with `using std::ostringstream;` (or just use `std::ostringstream` directly qualified).

Comment: how to change it if we use  std::cout ?

Comment: @user3021930, I don't understand the question.  But if you want to print the name out once you've constructed it, you can just write `cout << name << "\n";`.  Alternatively, you could just stream it into `cout` rather than `oss` in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent would be:

```
#include <sstream>

std::ostringstream s;
s << "jari" << rank + 42 + size << ".jpg";
std::string name = s.str();
```

Not exactly equivalent in terms of data types, since the final result is a `std::string` instead of a `char*`, but the most idiomatic.

Outputting the formated string directly is even simpler:

```
std::cout << "jari" << rank + 42 + size << ".jpg";
```

Alternatively, there is also the [Boost Format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/format/doc/format.html) library that offers similar functionality:

```
#include <boost/format.hpp>

boost::format formatter("jari%1%.jpg");
formatter % rank+42+size;
std::string name = formatter.str();
```

or to directly output the string:

```
std::cout << boost::format("jari%1%.jpg") % rank+42+size;
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can use boost format library

```
cout << boost::format("jari%1%.jpg") % (rank + 42 + size)
```